# Filenames with . in batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a Windows batch file that used to work but since I changed laptop, it fails.

I guess it's caused by points (.) in my file path but I haven't been able to find a way around this issue.

I basically pass a file name to my batch file and let it process it but it fails when it starts reading lines from the file:

```
echo MBP File: %1
rem Check that the file is a MapBasic Project File
if /I "%~sx1" NEQ ".mbp" (
    echo Error: file %~dpnx1 is not a MapBasic Project File ^(^*.mbp^)
    goto :EOF
) else (
    echo file %1 is a MapBasic Project File ^(^*.mbp^)
)

echo Looping MBP
for /f "usebackq skip=1 delims== tokens=2" %%j in (%1) do (
    echo Checking input file from MBP
    echo j: %%j
    SET filemb=%~dp1%%j
    ....
```

The output looks like this:

```
file "D:\Dropbox (Some-Name)\3. MB_Kode\mbInfoSelHandler\mbcode\InfoSelHandler.mbp" is a MapBasic Project File (*.mbp)
Looping MBP
\3. was unexpected at this time.
```

As you can see the last echo'ed text is `Looping MBP`

The file contains lines like these:

```
[LINK]
Application=..\InfoSelHandler.mbx
Module=Library\ARRAYLib.mbo
Module=Library\CONFIGFILELib.mbo
Module=Library\DEBUGLib.mbo
```

I'm assuming there's an issue in this line, but I'm not sure:

```
for /f "usebackq skip=1 delims== tokens=2" %%j in (%1) do (
```

Any hints?

Comment: Add quotes `"%~dp1"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit more explanation why you should always use quotes.

When a path contains parenthesis or ampersands you are in trouble, like in
`C:\Program and files (x86)\Tools&Help\bla.txt`

When you use it wihout surround it propper with quotes you get a syntax error.

Simplified code

```
for /f "usebackq" %%j in (%1) do (
    SET var=%~dp1
)
```

The `FOR /F` itself works, as long as `%1` is surrounded by quotes, but when they are missing it fails.

But the `SET var=%~dp1` breaks the code, as it's expanded when the FOR block is parsed to

```
set var=C:\Program and files (x86)\Tools&Help\bla.txt
```

The closing parenthesis of `x86)` closes the FOR block and the `\Tools&Help\bla.txt` are outside of the block and creates a syntax error.

```
    for /f "usebackq" %%j in (%1) do (
        SET var=C:\Program and files (x86)\Tools&Help\bla.txt
    )
```

In your case, you should modify the code to

```
for /f "usebackq skip=1 delims== tokens=2" %%j in ("%~1") do (
    echo Checking input file from MBP
    echo j: %%j
    SET "filemb=%~dp1%%j"
)
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be SET filemb="%~dp1%%j" in stead of SET "filemb=%~dp1%%j" ? Notice that I have moved the quote to only be arounds the text on the right side of the =

Comment: @PeterHorsbøllMøller No, it's the extended syntax of the SET command `SET "var=content"` to avoid problems with some characters and trailing white spaces. It safes the content, but doesn't add the quotes to the content, Inspite of `SET filemb="%~dp1%%j"` that would add quotes

Comment: Thanks, @jeb. I have much to learn about the world of batch scripting :-)